# django application loading very slow in IE

Tags: python, django

Our Django application is working without problems in Chrome but it is tiresome when using IE.

Running the application using `manage.py runserver` works fine but in our production site, it is very slow. Navigating from page to page is very slow.

How can we improve the app's performance in IE? We've already tried reducing our js and css lines and optimizing our js and css code but that hasn't helped.

Comment: It sounds like you use `./manage.py runserver` in production. If you do, don't.

Comment: Why you think it has something to do with Django if the site is slow in a particular browser? Django is a backend system. If the site is running slow in specific browsers this is clearly a problem of the frontend!

Though in any case, I agree with MindVirus to not run `manage.py runserver` in production.

Comment: probably your IE is generally slow or you have certain js that is slow on IE

Comment: I suggest to use some profiler to detect your problems. Say django-toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Django is not responsible for your site being slow in IE.The following might be the reason:

1) You might have heavy images/javascript in you page.use YSLOW/PSO to debug it.

2) Try seving  a webserver like apache and not with django.

Comment: Thanks. We don't use manage.py in live. I have tested the pages with YSlow and IE9 Developer tool bar. Even though it shows the load is due to js(we are using jquery), disabling javascript also taking more page load time. Confusing :-)